# PHP Extract Values from JSON Array for REST API

Tags: php, arrays, api, rest

Hi I'm working on a simple, universal REST API to read the first name and email address from a JSON POST call I'm using a sample test POST to pass these values across to the script.

```
{
    "fname": "Viktor",
    "email": "sample@emailhere.net"
}
```

Here's the code

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json);
print_r ($data);
```

it works fine and returns

```
stdClass Object ( [fname] => Ram [email] => Ram@gmail.com )
```

...but when I try to extract a specific element from the $data it returns a 500 server error - i.e. I added these 3 lines

```
$email = $data[0]["email"];
$fname = $data[0]["fname"];
print "email: $email fname: $fname";
```

What is the correct syntax to extract this simple JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is not an array. Plus, `json_decode` returns object by default, you need to set it to associative array mode. Correct code will be

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$email = $data["email"];
$fname = $data["fname"];
print "email: $email fname: $fname";
```